# apk file not opening using default program instead opening through notepad

Tags: windows

I downloaded a file with .apk extension and accidentally opened it using notepad. After that I'm unable to open it using the default program.Here I'm not trying to install that apk file but to access it contents and so I am not using any downloaded application to open apk file.I tried looking for some answers on google but was unable to resolve it. I tried opening it using "restore previous version" option but there wasn't any previous option, it was empty. What should I do?

Comment: If you're not using any downloaded application, what _is_ the default program supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Right click `->` "Open With" `->` "Choose Another App" `->` Pick the app you want to be the new default.